# How to handle rails enums?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I handle enums in rails? I have googled this, but not finding any clean solutions. So far I have come up with including the concern below on models that use interaction_type_id. This is my foreign key to my enum table in the database. Using this approach I don't have to use ids all over my code, but when saving an object that relates to an interact_type I can say

```
myobject.interaction_type = :file_download
```

This can then persist the the database with the correct id since the concern(see concern below - included on models that use the enum) will return the correct id.

```
module InteractionTypeEnum
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    INTERACTION_TYPE = { file_download: 1, email: 2, telesales: 3, registration: 4, enrolment: 5 }
  end

  def interaction_type
    INTERACTION_TYPE.key(read_attribute(:interaction_type_id)).to_s.gsub('_',' ').capitalize
  end

  def interaction_type=(s)
    write_attribute(:interaction_type_id, INTERACTION_TYPE[s])
  end
end
```

This just feels heavy. There must be an easier/cleaner way. Now when trying to write tests for this it gets even more messy.

Most of the reasons for wanting my enums in code and database are performance (code) and reporting (database).

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [active_enum](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum) gem.

Example from their docs, if you have an integer column called `sex` on the class `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enumerate :sex do
    value :name => 'Male'
    value :name => 'Female'
  end
end
```

Or you can define the enum in a seperate class:

```
class Sex < ActiveEnum::Base
  value 1 => 'Male'
  value 2 => 'Female'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enumerate :sex, :with => Sex
end
```

I like the abstraction it provides, and it saves you from having to create an entire database table just to store your enum values.

Comment: Nice solution, but lets say you now store the user in the database and you want to access the gender of the user via the back end. Are you saying this should be stored as a string in the database - male, female. What would happen if your enum set grew to 10 items and wouldn't change after that. Would you not want this information in a table in the database? In some cases you also might want to extend an enum to include other information like rank/order or description. I see how this is useful and clean, but it might be a little limited.

Comment: It's stored as an integer in the database, and there's much more functionality than what I've copy-pasted here (e.g. you can add extended info to an enum like you describe.) I'd recommend giving it a go if only to learn more about it and see if it suits your purposes; I've used it in multiple projects and never had a problem. But of course it's not the only solution (I'm sure there are other enum gems too, or you can roll your own like the other answer) and I'm not too heavily invested in it, other suggestions will work too.

Comment: I have checked out github. Looks really good, but it seems like it doesn't support rails 4. When I enable config.extend_classes = [ ActiveRecord::Base ] in the code and try run rails console I get /Users/ryanme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `class_inheritable_accessor' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError) ------- From what I have read class_inheritable_accessor has been deprecated.

Comment: I see rails 4.1.0.beta1 has enums built in. Might be a good way to go.

Comment: Oh yeah, the version on Rubygems is incompatible with Rails 4, that tripped me up before. Try adding `gem 'active_enum', github: 'adzap/active_enum'` to your Gemfile, that worked me. Damn, I sound like an evangelist for this gem, really I don't care that much either way, it's just the only solution I've ever bothered to learn about! Didn't know that enums were coming in 4.1.0, that sounds like a good improvement.

Comment: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html Just for reference :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method, say I have

```
class PersonInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person_info_type
end
```

and `PersonInfoType` is a simple domain table, containing the possible types of information.

Then I code my model as follows:

```
class PersonInfoType < ActiveRecord::Base

  PHONE = 1
  EMAIL = 2
  URL = 3

end
```

I have a seed fills the database with the corresponding data.

And so when assigning some person-information can do something like

```
person.person_infos << PersonInfo.create(:info => 'http://www.some-url.com', :person_info_type_id => PersonInfoType::URL)
```

This code can then be further cleaned up using relations:

```
class PersonInfo

  belongs_to :person_info_type

  def self.phones
    PersonInfo.where(:person_info_type_id => PersonInfoType::PHONE)
  end

end

person.person_infos << PersonInfo.phones.create(:info => '555 12345')
```